# APEX PMD Security Error

Tags: apex, security, salesforcedx-cli, pmd

Added Chrome PMD Extension `Salesforce Advanced Code Searcher` to run PMD script for my Apex Controller.

[image]

Below Code doesn't shows any security error.

```
if(  
            Programs__c.SObjectType.getDescribe().isAccessible()  &&
            Schema.SObjectType.Programs__c.fields.Program_Type__c.isAccessible()  && 
            Schema.SObjectType.Programs__c.fields.Service_Center__c.isAccessible()  && 
            Schema.SObjectType.Programs__c.fields.Is_Parent_Program__c.isAccessible()&&
            Schema.SObjectType.Programs__c.fields.Enroll_Last_Date__c.isAccessible()){ 
                programType = [SELECT Program_Type__c FROM Programs__c 
                               WHERE Service_Center__c =:serviceCenterId AND Is_Parent_Program__c = true 
                               and Enroll_Last_Date__c >=Today  group by Program_Type__c];
            }
```

I have gone through the blog, Salesforce introduces the "**WITH SECURITY_ENFORCED**" clause in Spring 19 as beta

http://amitsalesforce.blogspot.com/2019/07/field-level-security-in-soql-with-SECURITY-ENFORCED.html

I removed that If conditions in my code and added `WITH SECURITY_ENFORCED` at the end of my SOQL as below

```
programType = [SELECT Program_Type__c FROM Programs__c 
WHERE Service_Center__c =:serviceCenterId AND Is_Parent_Program__c = true 
and Enroll_Last_Date__c >=Today  WITH SECURITY_ENFORCED  group by Program_Type__c];
```

If I re-ran the APEX PMD, it's showing the Security error in the above statement.

Either Way, I Installed the `APEX PMD` extension in Visual Studio Code and ran `Apex Static Analysis: On File`, It's not showing the Security error for both scenarios.

Can anyone help, what I am missing here.

Comment: What was the error?

Comment: @sfdcfox --> Validate CRUD permission before SOQL/DML operation (rule: Security-ApexCRUDViolation)

Comment: Perhaps the browser plugin is using an old version of the ruleset for the PMD engine?